# RED5 and RTSP streaming

Tags: java, red5, rtsp

I have installed Red5 server. Now I have a video and want that to be streamed over RTSP in 3Gp format. How do I set that up?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to deploy oflaDemo in your red5 server. For that

- Download this war file http://red5.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3990/snapshots/oflaDemo-r3989-java6.war.
- Copy that into webapps folder.
- Restart the red5 server.

Now you have to copy your video files into /webapps/oflaDemo/streams folder

By default red5 gives a flash player for playing streming media files. To access that http://YOUR_RED5_SERVER:5080/demos/ofla_demo.html

OR

You can access the same RTMP video via VLC using this rtmp://YOUR_RED5_SERVER/oflaDemo/YOUR_FILE_NAME.3gp

OR

write your own player.

Comment: The question was about RTSP not RTMP